# How to upgrade Ubuntu without updating third party packages

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I recently upgraded one of our dev servers from Ubuntu 18 to 20. The commands I used in order are:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade  -y
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo reboot
sudo apt --purge autoremove
sudo apt install update-manager-core 
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

We run on AWS with Ubuntu installed. And we had additionally installed couchdb, & elastic search as well. During the upgrade process above elastic search was upgraded from v6.8.0 to v6.8.15.

Is there a way I can do an OS upgrade without updating elassticsearch in this case. So I need to upgrade from 18 to 20 but need ES to stay at v6.8.0?

Comment: There seem to be a few relevant hints at https://askubuntu.com/questions/781651/how-to-disable-upgrade-update-of-selective-packages-permanently.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent Couchdb and elastic search package from being upgrade by disabling  its repositories in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d.` (put `#` at the beginning of the URLs).

Also you can use `apt-mark` to mark a package as held back:

```
sudo apt-mark hold <package>
```

Comment: Thanks @GAD3R I'll try this in my next server and mark the answer as correct if it works.

Comment: This is the wrong answer. Ubuntu simply won't allow it and there's no way you can skip this, regardless of what role the packages in the OS have.

Comment: I can confirm this does not work - tried upgrading Ubuntu 18 to 20 and "holding" a third party package. I still received the same message.